# compare and merge two List of Lists in java which produces final List of Lists

Tags: java, list, merge

I have two list of ArrayList where i want to compare merge them final list of ArrayList.

example i have Database calls where i get these items as

```
List<List<String>> data1 = dao1.getall();
List<List<String>> data2 = dao2.getall();
```

data1 looks like result set of

```
"results": [
    [
      "India",
      "Idea",
      "30"
    ],
    [
      "USA",
      "Idea",
      "10"
    ],
    [
      "irland",
      "Idea",
      "10"
    ]
```

data2 looks like result set of

```
"results": [
    [
      "India",
      "Idea",
      "50"
    ],
    [
      "usa",
      "Idea",
      "30"
    ],
    [
      "sweden",
      "Idea",
      "10"
    ]
```

I would like to merge these two List of Lists as shown below by comparing the Country and Operator field.

```
"results": [
    [
      "India",
      "Idea",
      "30",
      "50",
      "80" ====== sum of the above two values
    ],
    [
      "usa",
      "Idea",
      "10",
      "30",
      "40"
    ],
    [
      "irland",
      "Idea",
      "10"
      "0"
      "10"
    ] 
    [
      "sweden",
      "Idea",
      "0"
      "10"       ==== order is very important here 
      "10"
    ]
```

Can anyone help me here?Thanks in advance.

I tried this but not at all working for me.

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
Public class Hello{
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<String>> list1 = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
        List<List<String>> list2 = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

        // add data

        List<String> datalist1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        datalist1.add("India");
        datalist1.add("vodafone");
        datalist1.add("23");
        list1.add(datalist1);

        System.out.println(list1);
        List<String> datalist2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        datalist2.add("India");
        datalist2.add("vodafone");
        datalist2.add("20");
        list2.add(datalist2);
        System.out.println(list2);

        Collection<List<Country>> list3 = Stream.concat(list1.get(0).stream(), list2.get(0).stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Country::getCountryName, Country::getOperator, Country::merge)).values();

    }

    private static final class Country {
        private final String countryName;
        private final String operator;
        private final List<String> value;

        public Country(String countryName, String name, List<String> values) {
            this.countryName = countryName;
            this.operator = name;
            this.value = values;
        }

        public String getCountryName() {
            return countryName;
        }

        public String getOperator() {
            return operator;
        }

        public List<String> getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        /*
         * This method is accepting both Country and merging data that you need.
         */
        public static Country merge(Country country1, Country country2) {
            if (country1.getCountryName().equalsIgnoreCase(country2.getCountryName().toLowerCase())
                    && country1.getOperator().equalsIgnoreCase(country2.getOperator().toLowerCase())) {
                List<String> newValue = country1.getValue();
                newValue.add(country2.getValue().get(0));
                Integer Total = Integer.parseInt(country1.getValue().get(0)) + Integer.parseInt(country2.getValue().get(0));
                newValue.add(Total.toString());
                return new Country(country1.getCountryName(), country1.getOperator(), newValue);
            }
            return new Country(country1.getCountryName(), country1.getOperator(), country1.getValue());
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Do you already have any code trying to accomplish what you are asking for?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using java8, you could use Map and merge option here. You just need to implement your own merge method, that will join data from both Elements.

In below example I have called your class `Country`.

```
@Test
public void should_create_plain_text_tag_for_booking_init_rq() {
    List<Country> data1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Country> data2 = new ArrayList<>();

    Collection<Country> results = Stream.concat(data1.stream(), data2.stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Country::getCountryName, // I asume that you want to merge Data with same country name.
                    Function.identity(),
                    Country::merge)
            ).values();

}

static class Country {
    private final String countryName;
    private final String name;
    private final List<Integer> values;

    public Country(String countryName, String name, List<Integer> values) {
        this.countryName = countryName;
        this.name = name;
        this.values = values;
    }
    /*  This method is accepting both Country and merging data that you need. */
    public static Country merge(Country country1, Country country2) {
        List<Integer> newValue  = country1.getValues();
        newValue.addAll(country2.getValues());
        // compute sum here;
        return new Country(country1.getCountryName(), country1.getName(), newValue);
    }
    // getters
    }
```